# Waiting for event inside Unity Coroutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

So I have a Unity coroutine method, in which I have some objects. These objects represent values that are being gathered from a server somewhere, and they send out an `Updated` event when they are ready.

I was wondering what the best way is to wait for all the values to be updated, inside a coroutine in Unity.

```
public IEnumerator DoStuff()
{
    foreach(var val in _updateableValues)
    {
        if (val.Value != null) continue;
        else **wait for val.Updated to be fired then continue**
    }
    //... here I do stuff with all the values
    // I use the WWW class here, so that's why it's a coroutine
}
```

What would be the best way of doing something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why we cannot use AutoResetEvent ? Do something on CPU is bad idea. Try use events.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

A spin-lock is a solution, however not a very CPU-gentle one. In a spin-lock, you would just wait for the variable to have a certain value, otherwise sleep for a few milliseconds.

```
public IEnumerator DoStuff()
{
     /* wait until we have the value we want */
     while( value != desiredValue)
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.001f);
    //after this loop, start the real processing
}
```

Maybe you might want to think about restructuring your code, sothat no spin-lock is requiered, but a more interupt/event-based based approach can be implemented. That means, if you update a value and something has to take place after it happened, kick it off directly after changing that value. In C#, there's even an interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for that design pattern (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), but you can easily design that yourself, too, e.g. by firing an event when that certain value has changed. We'd need more information on what exactly you want to react here, if you want a better solution than a spinlock, but this should give you some ideas.

Comment: Ah yes, I have such an event. The var.Updated I spoke about in my question is an event that is fired when the value is updated. I was hoping there would be something like `yield return new WaitForUpdateEventOf(myObject)` or something.

Comment: You *could* hook the `Update` event to set a flag to `true`, on which you will wait in your spin-lock, **or**, try to restructure the logic, e.g. processing everything on an `Update`. In what context are these updates happening on what object, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I think that a better option is to wait until the next frame using :
yield return null;
because it's the smallest time you can wait and it's more elegnt then WaitForSeconds when you don't know how much time you really want to wait.

Answer (score 9):

There is no builtin direct method to wait for the event itself, but you can use a **synchronous nested coroutine** to wait for a flag set by the event:

```
//Flag
bool eventHappened;

//Event subscriber that sets the flag
void OnEvent(){
    eventHappened=true;
}

//Coroutine that waits until the flag is set
IEnumerator WaitForEvent() {
    yield return new WaitUntil(eventHappened);
    eventHappened=false;
}

//Main coroutine, that stops and waits somewhere within it's execution
IEnumerator MainCoroutine(){
   //Other stuff...
   yield return StartCoroutine(WaitForEvent());
   //Oher stuff...
}
```

---

With that in mind, creating a generic coroutine that waits for an `UnityEvent` is easy:

```
private IEnumerator WaitUntilEvent(UnityEvent unityEvent) {
    var trigger = false;
    Action action = () => trigger = true;
    unityEvent.AddListener(action.Invoke);
    yield return new WaitUntil(()=>trigger);
    unityEvent.RemoveListener(action.Invoke);
}
```

Comment: In at least Unity 2021, WaitUntil requires a Func i.e. it's basically the same WaitUntil call as in your 2nd snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a better way is to check the sever every frame and not to wait for the an amount of time without any thinking.

```
public IEnumerator DoStuff()
{
     /* wait until we have the value we want */
     while( value != desiredValue)
     yield return null
     //after this loop, start the real processing
}
```

This is my little fix.

Answer (score -1):

I use the WaitUntil directly where I need it. I found though, that WaitUntil doesn't want a boolean but expects a boolean predicate function - so I provide this in my example below.

The example is real running code from a game. It runs in the very first scene, where I start the music before I do - the slightly lengthly - loading of the other stuff.

```
     //         
     public class AudioSceneInitializer : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private GlobalEventsSO globalEvents;
        //globalEvents is a scriptable object that - in my case - holds all events in the game
        [SerializeField] private AudioManager audioManager;
        //The audio manager which in my case will raise the audio ready event
        [SerializeField] public GameObject audioGO;// contains AudioSources used by AudioManager
        private bool audioReady = false;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        IEnumerator Start()
        {
            if (audioManager != null)
            //better check, if we don't produce the event, we wait forever
            {
                //subscribe to event
                globalEvents.audioManagerReadyEvent += OnAudioReady;
                //do something to raise the event - else we wait forever
                audioManager.onInitialization(this);//"this" needed to hand over the audioGO to the AudioManager
                //  waits until the flag is set;
                yield return new WaitUntil(IsAudioReady);
              
            }
            //now that we have music playing, we load the actual game 
            SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(1, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
        }  
        //Event subscriber that sets the flag
        void OnAudioReady()
        {
            //unsubscribing, if - as in my case - it happens only once in the game
            globalEvents.audioManagerReadyEvent -= OnAudioReady;
            audioReady = true;
        }
        //predicate function that WaitUntil expects
        private bool IsAudioReady()
        {
            return audioReady;
        }
        public void OnDisable()
        {
            audioManager.onCleanup();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: I deleted the rhethoric question...I wasn't aware of that rule

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have phrased misleadingly. It is not a rule. It is just a risk to be misunderstood. If you are not misunderstood everything is fine. But at least one user here is so doggishly single-minded (Natty will not begrudge me for being described like that) that they think "If it has a '?' then it is not an answer." When I wrote "I recommend" it was literal. I recommend it. Nothing more. Have fun.